# modificational scope of "two years ago"

Tags: adverbial-phrases, attachment-ambiguity, post-modifier

In the following sentence, does the "two years ago" describe the time of
buying or reading the book?

> 1. I bought the book **which** I had read two years ago and
>    **which** had the author's autograph.

Now, if it is changed into the following, is it possible for the "two years
ago" to describe the time of buying the book?

> 2. I bought the book **which** I had read two years ago, and
>    **it** had the author's autograph.

Comment: Both sentences give the strong impression that you read the book two years ago although both are capable of being interpreted the other way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm investigating the possibility of a time adverbal modifying the main clause, when it linearly follows a relative clause. Let us examine the following sentences:

1. I read the book which John gave me every day.


Is this one correct, with "every day" describing the time of reading the book (however awkward it is)?


2. I read the book which John gave me every day and which has a flowery pattern on its cover.


Is this one correct, with "every day" describing the time of reading the book? Note that there are two relative clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *I bought the book* [*which I had read two years ago*] [*and which had the*
> *author's autograph*].
>
> [2] *I bought the book* [*which I had read two years ago*], *and it had the*
> *author's autograph*.

[1] and [2] have the same meaning: you bought the book; you had read the book two years ago; the book had the author's autograph.

The temporal PP "two years ago" doesn't 'follow' the relative clause, as you put it, but is actually part of it. Thus "which I had read two years ago" modifies "book", not "bought".

If you want the relative clause to refer to "bought" you'll need to use a non-defining relative, as in [3].

> [3] *I bought the book, which I had already read, two years ago*.

though it would be better with an adverb such as "already", as shown.

Note, though, that non-defining relatives are supplements, not modifiers.

Comment: The question is actually related to another: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254200/just-at-the-time-that-i-dated-my-creation/254212?noredirect=1#comment477478_254212 . I suspect Mary Shelley's sentence, when considered in relation to the larger context, is wrong.